# on limits of cumulative density functions

Tags: probability, self-learning

Theorem 1.5.3 of *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger States that the function $F(x)$ is a cdf if and only if the following three conditions hold:

1) $\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(x) = 0 \text{ and } \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1.$

2)   $\ldots$

Now, how would I go to prove the forward direction of this first condition?

By definition we would need to find, for every $\epsilon > 0$, an $N> x \text{ s.t. } |F(x)|< \epsilon$

I am having some problems finding the relationship between $\epsilon$ and $N$ as I would do with a limit of a real function to formally prove a limit. How is this Done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as a "cumulative density function".  There are cumulative distribution functions (cdf) and there are probability density functions (pdf).  But the word "cumulative" contradicts the word "density". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"cdf" = "cumulative distribution function"

"pdf" = "probability density function"

nothing = "cumulative density function".  The words "cumulative" and "density" contradict each other.  Densities are intensive and cumulative things are extensive.

\begin{align}
F(x) = \Pr(X\le x) & = \Pr\left( \left\{ \lfloor x\rfloor \le X < x \right\} \cup \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} \left\{ n \le X<n+1 \right\} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr\left( \lfloor x\rfloor \le X < x \right) + \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} \Pr( n \le X<n+1 ) \le 1.
\end{align}
So this is a convergent series of non-negative terms.  If $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m <\infty$ and $\forall m,\ a_m\ge0$, then
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{m=M}^\infty a_m = 0.
$$
This follows from the fact that
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^M a_m = \text{the sum of the whole series.}
$$

Comment: I apologize for having messed up the wording. Thanks for your response, I am wondering If you can explain the fact that $\lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{m=M}^\infty a_m = \text{the sum of the whole series.}$ or point me to a reference that could help.

Comment: Sorry, a typo: I meant $\lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^M a_m=$the sum of the whole series. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks, Clear. Could you tell me in witch probability books proofs of this kind are given in a rigorous manner. Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger did not seem to dwell on these technicalities that to me are interesting. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You might try Rosenthal's _First look at rigorous probability theory_.